# Rounding to multiple places in Crsytal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I don't know if this is even possible to do on Crystal reports. What I have is a list of how to report results depending on where the result falls. So if the result (raw data) is 1.63 then I have to round it to the nearest 0.1 so it would be 1.6.
Here is the list:

```
0-1.0 round to nearest 0.05
1-10 round to nearest 0.1
10-40 round to nearest 1
40-100 round to nearest 5
100-400 round to nearest 10
400-1000 round to nearest 50
1000+ round to nearest 100
```

I thought using ceiling/floor would work but I don't know what I am doing wrong because it is asking for a boolean right after the then. This is the formula I was attempting to use. Our system uses one form of rounding so we were hoping to use the report to help with the rounding issue.

```
If ({PRM_SxData.nResult} in 0 to 1.0 )
then (Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.05)) and (Floor   
({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.05))
else 
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} in 1.01 to 10
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.1)) and (Floor 
({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.1)))
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} in 10.01 to 40
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 1)) and (Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 
1)))
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} in 40.01 to 100
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 5)) and (Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 
5))) 
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} in 100.01 to 400
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 10)) and (Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 
10)))
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} in 400.01 to 1000
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 50)) and (Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 
50)))
else 
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} > 1000.01
then ((Ceiling ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 100)) and (Floor 
({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 100)))
else " "
```

It's messy but it is the best I can come up with.

Comment: why are you using both ceiling and floor?

Comment: @siva I have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
If ({PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 0 and {PRM_SxData.nResult}<= 1.0 )
then Floor({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.05)
else 
IF {{PRM_SxData.nResult} >= in 1.01 and {PRM_SxData.nResult} <= 10
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 0.1)
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 10.01 and {PRM_SxData.nResult} <= 40
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 1)
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 40.01 and {PRM_SxData.nResult} <= 100
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 5) 
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 100.01 and {PRM_SxData.nResult} <= 400
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 10)
else
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 400.01 and {PRM_SxData.nResult} <= 1000
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 50)
else 
IF {PRM_SxData.nResult} >= 1000.01
then Floor ({PRM_SxData.nResult}, 100)
else 0
```